# Wiring dishwasher without a ground wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, dishwasher

I'm trying to replace my old dishwasher. It's hardwired. My new dishwasher has three wires,1 white wire (neutral) 1 black (hot) and 1 green which I know is ground. The problem is the wiring coming from my house only has two wires no ground wire. What do I do. Is there anything I can do to ground this.

Comment: Age of house?   Less than 60 years, would expect ground available.   Does your house use metal conduit(pipes the wire goes in/though)?  Conduit is used for ground path, instead of a separate ground wire.

Comment: A fast test is to use a multimeter.  Hot and neutral should have ~120 volts.  Hot and metal junction box if grounded should also give a reading of ~120 volts.  Hot and not grounded box should be zero.

Comment: Can you post photos of where the house wiring exits the wall please?

Comment: If you really don't have ground available, ground can be connected from elsewhere. Since a dishwasher is on a 15A or 20A circuit, that means you should be able to connect it to the ground of one of your kitchen receptacle circuits.

Comment: Hope you made a photo of the old whirring. It would be very uncommon, or even dangerous not to have ground on the dishwasher.

Comment: The  cold  water copper pipe may be used for ground.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's not always a safe assumption to make. My parents' house has some copper piping in various parts, but all the pipes in the basement were replaced with pex, meaning that *none* of the copper piping was grounded in any way.  (House was originally plumbed with galvanized pipe, newer add-on/replacement work over the years was done with copper, then the remaining galvanized pipe in the basement was replaced with pex.)  Also, I don't think the plumbing is an acceptable grounding method per Code anyway.

Answer (score 3):

### Your best bet is to provide GFCI protection to that circuit.

"But wait. I thought GFCI was a *receptacle*.  How do you put that on a hardwired appliance?"

Actually, GFCI comes in many forms, including GFCI breakers, or standalone GFCIs.

Because GFCI is actually a zone of protection, that protects anything wired into it.  Well, I mean obviously, a GFCI *that is a receptacle* is going to extend GFCI protection to its own sockets. But all of them have a way to extend GFCI protection further.

They have a set of terminals called "Load" which are exclusively for that purpose (and should never be used for anything else).

So your best bet is to follow the dishwasher circuit's cable back to the source.  If there are receptacles on it, that receptacle can be replaced with a GFCI receptacle with the dishwasher leg placed on the GFCI's "Load" terminals.

If there is a shutoff switch for the dishwasher (modern Code requires this on hardwired dishwashers), and neutral comes through that switch, a GFCI switch can be installed there. (the Test and Reset buttons are used for On and Off. Clever.)

If there is no other option, a GFCI breaker can be installed.  Or if that is cost-prohibitive or unavailable, the circuit wires can be rerouted to stop at a junction box prior to the panel, and a GFCI receptacle or standalone can be installed there.